# How to collect multiple reactions from one user?

Tags: discord.js

Basically, I am trying to make it so a user can trigger a command that gives them 30 seconds to hit various reactions. It would collect reactions and later use them.

Everything I have tried to be able to use a command and get it to wait for multiple reactions has not worked.

Flat out, I am not good at this. I don't really even know a lot about JS. I am just trying to put something together for my friends and I. I am not asking someone to do everything for me, just need a framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Message#awaitReactions()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=awaitReactions) (the discord.js guide has a [topic](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#await-messages) on collectors you might want to read). The first parameter to this function is a filter, which passes [`reaction`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageReaction) and [`user`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User).

If you're adding reactions beforehand, you might want to make sure that the reaction is one of the aforementioned selected few. You should also make sure that the user is the message author.

The second parameter is for [`options`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/AwaitReactionsOptions). The option you're looking for is [`time`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/CollectorOptions). This property takes a number of milliseconds, and when that amount of time is up, it will resolve the promise the function returns in a [`Collection`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection). Your finished code might look like this:

```js
// react with your emojis
await message.react('');
await message.react('');

// create the filter function
const filter = (reaction, user) => 
  ['', ''].includes(reaction.emoji.name) // compare emojis
  && user.id === message.author.id // compare users

// call the function
const collected = await message.awaitReactions(
  filter, // pass the filter
  { time: 30000 } // set the time limit
);

// log your findings!
console.log(collected);
```